# Error copying a string in C

Tags: c, runtime-error

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void string_copy(char * dst,char * src);

int main(){
    char stringA[] = "Hello";
    char stringB[10];

    string_copy(stringB,stringA);

    printf("%s",stringB);
    return 0;

}

void string_copy(char * dst,char * src){
    if(src == NULL || dst == NULL) return;

    while(*src != '\n'){
        *dst = *src;
        dst++;
        src++;
    }
}
```

I can't understand why this code doesn't works.
I get:

> Error: the program has stopped working

How can I resolve?

Comment: check against '\0' and make it a do-while loop (or write `*dst = '\0'`) at the end to ensure that result is null-terminated

Comment: This is a very nicely presented question.  Good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `'\0'` instead of `'\n'`:

Try this:

```
void string_copy(char * dst,char * src){
    if(src == NULL || dst == NULL) return;

    while(*src != '\0'){
        *dst = *src;
        dst++;
        src++;
    }
    *dst = '\0'; // <-- need to add this 
}
```

`\0` is the NULL char

`\n` is new line char

Answer (score 2):

You should write `while(*src != '\0')`. Strings in C are terminated by NULL character '\0', not by newline '\n'.

Comment: `while( *src != 0 )` is more simple and the same. Or even `while( *src )`.

Comment: Yeah `while(*src)` of course is the shortest. But i think being explicit is sometimes good, at least for OP now.

Comment: @i486 An explicit cast `\0` is much better, as it expresses your intent - it is self-documenting code. `while(*src)` is bad style as it can easily be confused with `while(src)`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. '\n' in C is known as new line character.
> 2. '\0' in C by default signify end of the string.

So in the loop `while (*src != '\n')` instead of using `'\n'` use `'\0'`
. When while loop will identify `\0` at the end of `src` string it will terminate and by that time the `src` string would have been copied to the `dst` string.